# The Base in the mix

Tags: code-golf, math, base-conversion

**Input:**
A list/array of integers for which each item is in the range of `2-36`.

**Output:**
The sum of the integers (as base 10), where each next integer is in the base of the previous value (starting with a regular base 10).

**Example:**
Let's say we have an input like this: `[4, 12, 34, 20, 14, 6, 25, 13, 33]`
Then we have a sum like this:

```
4    (4  in base-10) +
6    (12 in base-4 ) +
40   (34 in base-12) +
68   (20 in base-34) +
24   (14 in base-20) +
6    (6  in base-14) +
17   (25 in base-6 ) +
28   (13 in base-26) +
42   (33 in base-13)
= 235
```

***Mathematical base explained:***
I considered assuming everyone knows how base works, but I'll give a brief example of how it works anyway, just in case. Let's take the `34 in base-12` for example, how did we get `40`?

```
1-34 in regular base-10:
 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34
 So, from 1 to 34 is 34 steps in base-10

1-34 in base-12:
 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, B, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 1A, 1B, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 2A, 2B, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34
 So, from 1 to 34 is 40 steps in base-12
```

[Here is perhaps a useful calculator.](http://planetcalc.com/2095/)

**Challenge rules:**

- Array size will be in reasonable range (like `1-100` / see test cases).
- The test cases will never contain integers of which the current value is invalid for it's previous base (i.e. You will never have something like `19 in base-6` or `6 in base-6`, because base-6 only contains the digits `0-5`).
- You can take the input any way you'd like. Can be as an int-array, as a comma/space-separated string, etc. Your call. (You are also allowed to take the int-array reversed, which could be useful for stack-based programming languages.)

**General Rules:**

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-golfing languages. Try to come up with as short an answer as possible for any programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer, so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code.
- Also, please add an explanation if necessary.

**Test cases:**

```
[4, 12, 34, 20, 14, 6, 25, 13, 33]                            ->   235
 4+ 6+  40+ 68+ 24+ 6+ 17+ 28+ 42

[5, 14, 2, 11, 30, 18]                                        ->   90
 5+ 9+  2+ 3+  33+ 38

[12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 12, 2, 11, 3, 10, 2, 10]    ->   98
 12+ 13+ 11+ 9+ 8+ 7+ 6+ 5+ 4+ 3+ 5+  2+ 3+  3+ 3+  2+ 2

[36, 36]                                                      ->   150
 36+ 114
```

Comment: For stack based languages which have a LIFO container, can the input be given in reversed order? In dc I would require ~30 bytes just to flip the stack to have the first number in the input be the first one to be processed, which non-stack based languages have by default.

Comment: @seshoumara Why not. I'll clarify this in the challenge. It's mainly about the challenge and output, and not really about the input-format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>7</s> <s>6</s> 5 bytes

Uses the [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/code-page.md) encoding.

Saved 1 byte using the new built-in `š` as suggested by *Kevin Cruijssen*

```
TšüöO
```

**Explanation**

Input list is taken reversed, as allowed by challenge specification.

```
Tš     # prepend a 10 to the list
  üö   # reduce by conversion to base-10
    O  # sum
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/5OjCw3sOb/P//z/a0EBHwUhHAUQZAylDCM8IzDPRUTDVUTDTUTDXUbDQUbCEKAOpMTSKBQA)

[Modified testsuite](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVql8eP3/kEOrDu85vM3/v85/Y2MFQ2MFI1MFMwVDEwUjAwVjEwVDIwUTLkMLBWMDBUNDBSOQhCmXoQGIBZSHihkBWUBxoD5zBQsFS5AUUMLQiMvYTMHYDAA)

Comment: Can be 5 bytes now with the builtin `š` instead of `¸ì`. Also, your explanation states "_append_" instead of "_prepend_". :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: Thank you :)

Answer (score 9):

## Python 3, 40 bytes

```python
lambda a:sum(map(int,map(str,a),[10]+a))
```

Tests are at **[ideone](http://ideone.com/7ZUpcU)**

`map(str, a)` creates a generator, `G`, that calls `str` on each value in `a`, converting to strings
`map(int, G, [10]+a)` creates a generator that calls `int(g, v)` for pairs across `G` and `[10]+a`
`int(g, v)` converts the string `g` from the integer base `v` (if `v` is in `[2,36]` and `g` is valid)
`sum` does what it says on the tin

Answer (score 7):

## Python 2, 48 bytes

```
lambda a:sum(int(`x`,y)for x,y in zip(a,[10]+a))
```

Tests are at **[ideone](http://ideone.com/ePipjY)**

`zip(a,[10]+a)` traverses pairs of the values in `a`, and the previous value or `10` for the first
the `backticks` in the `int` call convert `x` to a string, `s`
`int(s, y)` converts the string `s` from the integer base `y` (if `y` is in `[2,36]` and `s` is valid)
`sum` does what it says on the tin

Answer (score 6):

## Perl, <s>35</s> <s>34</s> 33 bytes

Includes +2 for `-ap`

Run with the list of numbers on STDIN:

```
basemix.pl <<< "4 12 34 20 14 6 25 13 33";echo
```

`basemix.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -ap
$\+=$&+"$`$& 10"*/.$/*$`for@F}{
```

I've been waiting for ages for a chance to use this abuse...

### Explanation

The input numbers can have at most 2 digits. A number `xy` in base `b` is simply `b*x+y`. I'm going to use the regex `/.$/` so the first digit ends up in `` $` `` and the last digit in `$&`, so the contribution to the sum is `` $&+$b*$` ``.

I abuse the fact that `for` does not properly localize the regex variables (like for example `map` and `while` do) so the results of a match in the previous loop is still available in the current loop. So if I'm careful about the order in which I do the operations the base is available as `` "$`$&" ``, except for the very first loop where I need the base to be 10. So I use `` "$`$& 10" `` instead

The way the first `$&` works is an abuse too since it is actually changed by the `/.$/` while it is already on the stack waiting to be added.

The final abuse is the `}{` at the end which changes the loop implied by `-p` from

```
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    ...code..
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
```

to

```
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    ...code..
}
{
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
```

Which means `$_` will be undefined in the print, but it still adds `$\` in which I accumulated the sum. It is also a standard golf trick to get post-loop processing

Comment: I'd be really interested in an explanation for those of us with weaker perl-fu!

Comment: @m-chrzan Solution fixed and explanation added

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, <s>53</s> 51 bytes

```
for(;$x=$argv[++$i];$b=$x)$s+=intval($x,$b);echo$s;
```

Iterates over the input, converting each input to string variant. Then takes the integer value using the previous number as base. For the first number, the base will not be set, PHP will then start off with 10 (inferred from the number format).

Run like this (`-d` added for aesthetics only):

```
php -d error_reporting=30709 -r 'for(;$x=$argv[++$i];$b=$x)$s+=intval($x,$b);echo$s;' -- 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 12 2 11 3 10 2 10;echo
```

### Tweaks

- Actually, no need to convert to string, as CLI arguments are already string. Saved 2 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## Java 7, <s>109</s> <s>89</s> 86 bytes

```
int c(int[]a){for(Byte i=1;i<a.length;a[0]+=i.valueOf(a[i]+"",a[++i-2]));return a[0];}
```

Golfed 20 bytes thanks to *@cliffroot* (of which 12 because of a stupid mistake I made myself).

**Ungolfed & test code:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/gPDKU2)

```
class M{
  static int c(int[] a){
     for(Byte i = 1; i < a.length; a[0] += i.valueOf(a[i]+"", a[++i-2]));
     return a[0];
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(c(new int[]{ 4, 12, 34, 20, 14, 6, 25, 13, 33 }));
    System.out.println(c(new int[]{ 5, 14, 2, 11, 30, 18 }));
    System.out.println(c(new int[]{ 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 12, 2, 11, 3, 10, 2, 10 }));
    System.out.println(c(new int[]{ 36, 36 }));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
235
90
98
150
```

Comment: Do you really need `p`? The sum can be computed like this, can't it: `r+=r.valueOf(""+a[i],a[i-1])`?

Comment: used conversion `+""` instead of `valueOf` and removed unnecessary variables – `int c(int[]a){for(Integer i=1;i<a.length;a[0]+=i.valueOf(a[i]+"",a[++i-2]));return a[0];}`

Comment: @cliffroot Ah, I'm an idiot.. When I was testing I made a mistake and had the `10` and `p` reversed. I realized the mistake and fixed it, but since the String part is now regular base-10 I can indeed remove the `toString` and just use `+""`.. Thanks, and also thanks for golfing the other things, -20 bytes. I really gotta make an answer you can't golf more (not that I don't appreciate it! the shorter the better of course - in code-golfing that is ;P)

Comment: Just to compare with my answer, yours in current Java's syntax is 79 bytes long (mine is presently 86 bytes long). But that's not fun taking others' code ;)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Feel free to post it as a separate answer. 86 bytes is still shorter than my previous 109 (-12 because of an obvious mistake, so 97) answer.

Comment: @cliffroot Btw, don't you mind that I edit your answer every time? If you post it as a separate answer you definitely get my (and other) upvotes for more rep. It's unfortunate comment upvotes aren't worth any rep..

Comment: @KevinCruijssen , I'm more than fine with it :) I just feel that realistically Java does not compete with all that 5-6 bytes solution, so I don't add my own answers often, but I still find it fun to golf down others' solution.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
ṙ1DḅṖḌS
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bmZMUThuIXhuZbhuIxT&input=&args=WzQsIDEyLCAzNCwgMjAsIDE0LCA2LCAyNSwgMTMsIDMzXQ)

Comment: You could replace `ṖḌ` with `F`

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work in the first number has two digits.

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript ES6, <s>45</s> <s>42</s> 41 Bytes

```js
const g =
     a=>a.map(v=>s+=parseInt(v,p,p=v),s=p=0)|s
;

console.log(g.toString().length);                                            // 42
console.log(g([4, 12, 34, 20, 14, 6, 25, 13, 33]));                          // 235
console.log(g([5, 14, 2, 11, 30, 18]  ));                                    // 90
console.log(g([12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 12, 2, 11, 3, 10, 2, 10] )); // 98
```

Conventiently `parseInt(x,0) === parseInt(x,10)`.

**edit**: Saved 1 byte thanks to @ETHproductions

Comment: Nice! I think you can save a byte by replacing `&&s` with `|s`.

Comment: You can also replace `const g` with just `g`

Answer (score 3):

## Java, 86 bytes

```
s->{int[]b={10};return s.reduce(0,(r,n)->{r+=n.valueOf(""+n,b[0]);b[0]=n;return r;});}
```

### Testing and ungolfed

```
import java.util.function.ToIntFunction;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ToIntFunction<Stream<Integer>> f = s -> {
      int[] b = {10};                 // Base, initialized with 10
      return s.reduce(0, (r, n) -> {  // Typical use of reduction, sum starts with 0.
        r += n.valueOf("" + n, b[0]); // Add the value in the previous base.
        b[0] = n;                     // Assign the new base;
        return r;
      });
    };

    System.out.println(f.applyAsInt(Stream.of(new Integer[]{4, 12, 34, 20, 14, 6, 25, 13, 33})));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Pure bash, 38

```bash
b=10
for i;{((t+=$b#$i,b=i));}
echo $t
```

The input list is given at the command-line.  `for i;` automatically iterates over the input parameters (equivalent to `for i in $@;`).

[Ideone.](https://ideone.com/l6myr3)

Answer (score 2):

### Actually, 12 bytes

```
;p(dX(♂$♀¿Σ+
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=O3AoZFgo4pmCJOKZgMK_zqMr&input=WzQsIDEyLCAzNCwgMjAsIDE0LCA2LCAyNSwgMTMsIDMzXQ)

Explanation:

```
;p(dX(♂$♀¿Σ+
;             dupe input
 p            pop first element from list
  (dX         pop and discard last element from other copy
     (♂$      stringify all elements in first copy
        ♀¿    for each pair of elements in the two lists, interpret the first element as a base-(second element) integer
          Σ   sum
           +  add first element of original list
```

Answer (score 2):

### [CJam](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), 15 bytes

```
l~{A\:A10bb}%:+
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=bH57QVw6QTEwYmJ9JTor&input=WzQgMTIgMzQgMjAgMTQgNiAyNSAxMyAzM10)

#### Explanation

```
l~     e# Read and evaluate input.
{      e# Map this block over the input...
  A    e#   Push A. Initially this is 10, afterwards it will be the value of the
       e#   last iteration.
  \:A  e#   Swap with current value and store that in A for the next iteration.
  10b  e#   Convert to base 10 to get its decimal digits.
  b    e#   Interpret those in the base of the previous A.
}%
:+     e# Sum all of those values.
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>54</s> <s>48</s> 40 bytes

I used a recursive approach.

```
f=([b,...a],c)=>b?parseInt(b,c)+f(a,b):0
```

Saved 6 bytes, thanks to Lmis!
Saved 8 more bytes, thanks to Neil!

Comment: I think you can save 3 bytes by using `parseInt(a,b)` instead of `parseInt(a[0],b)` since `parseInt` converts the first argument to string and ignores everything starting at the first invalid character (i.e. ',').

Comment: I also think you can save some bytes by using `a[0]?stuff():0` instead of `a.length&&stuff()`

Comment: @Lmis Thanks, I've updated it :)

Comment: I think you can shorten this to 40 bytes: `f=([b,...a],c)=>b?parseInt(b,c)+f(a,b):0`

Comment: @Neil nice way of not using the `slice` function

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <s>65</s> 59 bytes

```haskell
b%x|x<1=x|y<-div x 10=b*b%y+x-10*y
sum.((10:)>>=zipWith(%))
```

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/dWMAuf).

Answer (score 2):

## Matlab, 68 bytes

Not a very creative solution, but here it is:

```
function[s]=r(x);j=10;s=0;for(i=x)s=s+base2dec(num2str(i),j);j=i;end
```

Tests:

```
>> r([4,12,34,20,14,6,25,13,33])
ans =
   235
>> r([12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 12, 2, 11, 3, 10, 2, 10])
ans =
   98
>> r([5, 14, 2, 11, 30, 18])
ans =
   90
>> r([36,36])
ans =
   150
```

Comment: You can save one byte with `function s=r(x);...`

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>52</s>  50 bytes

```perl6
{sum (10,|@_).rotor(2=>-1).map:{+":{.[0]}<{.[1]}>"}}
{sum (10,|@_).rotor(2=>-1).map:{":{.[0]}<$_[1]>"}}
```

### Explanation:

```perl6
# bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢@_｣
{
  sum

    ( 10, |@_ )        # the input with a preceding 10
    .rotor( 2 => -1 )  # grab 2 values, back up one, repeat
    .map:
    {
      # create a string of the form ":10<4>"
      ":{
        .[0]            # first element from $_
      }<{
        .[1]            # second element from $_
      }>"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 52 bytes

```python
f=lambda x:x[1:]and int(`x.pop()`,x[-1])+f(x)or x[0]
```

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/CBEcYy).

Answer (score 1):

### Julia, 63 Bytes

```
f(l)=sum([parse(Int,string(l[i]),l[i-1])for i=2:length(l)])+l[]
```

Parses each number (except the first) taking the previous element as base and sums. Adds the first element at the end

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 52 bytes

```
->a{eval a.zip([10]+a).map{|e|'"%s".to_i(%s)'%e}*?+}
```

#### ungolfed

```
->a{
  eval(
    a.zip([10]+a).map { |e|
      '"%s".to_i(%s)' % e
    }.join("+")
  )
}
```

#### usage

```
f=->a{eval a.zip([10]+a).map{|e|'"%s".to_i(%s)'%e}*?+}
p f[[4, 12, 34, 20, 14, 6, 25, 13, 33]] # => 235
```

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 67 bytes

```
def f(a:Int*)=a zip(10+:a)map{t=>Integer.parseInt(""+t._1,t._2)}sum
```

Explanation:

```
def f(a: Int*) =     //declare a method f with varargs of type Int as parameter
a zip (10 +: a)      //zip a with 10 prepended to a, resulting in...
                     //...Array((4,10), (12,4), (34,12), (20,34), (14,20), (6,14), (25,6), (13,25), (33,13))
map { t =>           //map each tuple t to...
  Integer.parseInt(  //...an integer by parsing...
    ""+t._1, t._2    //...a string of the first item in base-second-item.
  )
}
sum                  //and sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 59 bytes

I wish Mathematica's function names were shorter. But otherwise I'm happy.

```
Tr[FromDigits@@@Transpose@{IntegerDigits/@{##,0},{10,##}}]&
```

For example,

```
Tr[FromDigits@@@Transpose@{IntegerDigits/@{##,0},{10,##}}]&[4,12,34,20,14,6,25,13,33]
```

yields `235`.

`{##,0}` is a list of the input arguments with 0 appended (representing the numerals); `{10,##}` is a list of the input arguments with 10 prepended (representing the bases). That pair of lists is `Transpose`d to associate each with numeral with its base, and `FromDigits` (yay!) converts each numeral-base pair to a base-10 integer, the results of which are summed by `Tr`.

Answer (score 1):

### Common Lisp, 83

```
(lambda(s)(loop for b ="10"then x for x in s sum(#1=parse-integer x :radix(#1#b))))
```

#### Details

```
(defun base-mix (list)
  (loop
     for base = "10" then string
     for string in list
     sum (parse-integer string :radix (parse-integer base))))
```

The `loop` construct accepts *"v then w"* iteration constructs, where *v* is an expression to be evaluated the first time the iteration variable is computed, and *w* is the expression to be evaluated for the successive iterations. Declarations are evaluated one after the other, so `base` is first "10", then the previous element `string`of the list `list` being iterated. The `sum` keyword computes a sum: the integer read from `string` with base *b*, where *b* is the integer parsed from the `base` string, in base 10. `#1=` and `#1#` are notations to define and use *reader variables*: the first affects an s-expression to a variable, the other one replaces the reference by the same object. This saves some characters for long names.

#### Example

```
(base-mix '("4" "12" "34" "20" "14" "6" "25" "13" "33"))
=> 235
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-x`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 7 bytes

```
äÏsnX}A
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LXg=&code=5M9zblh9QQ==&input=WzQsMTIsMzQsMjAsMTQsNiwyNSwxMywzM10=)

```
äÏsnX}A     :Implicit input of array
ä           :Take each consecutive pair of elements
 Ï          :Pass them through the following function as X & Y
  s         :  Convert Y to a base-10 string
   nX       :  Convert to an integer from base-X
     }      :End function
      A     :Before doing any of that, though, prepend 10 to the array
            :Implicit output of the sum of the resulting array
```